# To create a calendar with customized features such as add, edit events with color platelets using javascript & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've to create a basic calendar functionality where I can use any available calendar library for the purpose (Javascript/Jquery). When clicking on any date it should open a pop-up box, this pop-up will contain two fields.

1. Name of the Event
2. color palette (any 5 hard coded colors,) you can use radio button option for that.

After entering the event name and selecting a color, save this event on the calendar on selected date. On clicking on existing event we should be able to edit the event. I need not to save the events into database.

Comment: Did you try https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ?
You can use that as datepicker and create your own version of popup  for the fields you need

Comment: yeah, here's the code which works fine but I need additional features i.e popup (with add/edit event & assigning color to it) when clicked on particular date.

Comment: <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
      <style>
       
      </style>
  <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker-2" ).datepicker();
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div id="datepicker-2"></div>
</body>